# Estou com problemas para ler uma variável de um service em outros controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho um service em que crio uma variável que vou manipular e enviar para outro controller.

Esse é meu service

```
app.service("maissaude", [
  "$rootScope",
   function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.nomeMinimo = ""; //Variável que vou manipular e ler em outro controller
}]);
```

Nesse mesmo service tenho um método que salva um registro mínimo na api e me devolve o usuário salvo:

```
minimumRegistration: function(form, doctor) {
      maissaude.http.post({
        url: "url que vai na api salvar o dado",
        data: maissaude.signup.modelMinimum,
        callback: {
          success: function(data) {
            var nomeMinimo = data.name;
            $rootScope.nomeMinimo = nomeMinimo;//Atualizo meu nomeMinimo da mesma forma que fiz lá no início do método
            $window.location = "/login/#/cadastro/" + data.id;
          }
        }
      });
}
```

Em um outro controller eu leio esse $rootScope.nomeMinimo
Porém ele não vem com o dado que foi atribuído a ele depois de salvar o usuário,
Ele vem vazio do jeito que declarei lá em cima;

```
app.controller("CadastroController", [
  "$scope",
  "$rootScope",
  "maissaude",
  function($scope, $rootScope, maissaude) {
    console.log("Variável global!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log($rootScope.nomeMinimo);
  }
]);
```

Alguém consegue me falar o que tenho que fazer para conseguir ler esse console, o dado que manipulei no outro service. PLease!!

Comment: Moça, mas se você definiu um `service` para fazer isso, não deveria retornar um objeto, ao invés de um `$rootScope`?

Comment: Detalhe.... Esse `http.post` é uma lib do angular ou está usando algum outro framework Javascript? Faça um teste deixando um `$watch` registrado no `$rootScope` com o valor `nomeMinimo`. Tipo `$rootScope.$watch('nomeMinimo', (v) => console.log(v))`

Comment: Wallace eu vou retornar um objeto, mas eu preciso passar os dados Mínimos para o cliente terminar seu cadastro em outra página. Só que preciso manter o nome dos models.

Comment: Ah e eu estou usando AngularJS

Comment: Gabriela, mas se você colocar o valor diretamente no `maisservico` não funciona? Geralmente eu faço isso no angular e funcionar tranquilamente. Exemplo: `maisservico.nomeMinimo = data.name`

Comment: Se puder acessar, você pode [logar no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para poder explicar melhor o problema. Eu acho que seria legal colocar o source completo do  `maisservico` (claro, se isso não exibir alguma informação sensível)

Comment: Te perguntei sobre o método que você usa pra fazer requisição `$http` porque se for uma biblioteca externa (leia-se "que não está adptada ao angular")` talvez seja necessário executar um `$scope.$apply()` depois do `$window.location`

Comment: Ah entendi, estou tentando usar apenas o maissaude.nomeMinimo, eu até tenho uma isLogin, porém ela é no mesmo controller, já esse nome mínimo eu quero passar de um service para um controller

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79521/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-gabriela-mendonca).

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar o `$rootScope` para armazenar uma variável global não é uma boa prática porque sua variável estará disponível em todos os lugares da aplicação sem o devido tratamento. Você começou com a ideia correta de utilizar um `service` para isso. Vou deixar um exemplo simples de como compartilhar variáveis utilizando dois (ou mais) `controllers`.

```js
angular
  .module('minhaApp', []);

// Service para compartilhamento dos dados
angular
  .module('minhaApp')
  .factory('principalService', principalService);

principalService.$inject = [];

function principalService() {
  var service = {
    informacoes: {
      nomeMinimo: ''
    }
  };

  return service;
};

// Controller Primário
angular
  .module('minhaApp')
  .controller('ControllerPrimario', ControllerPrimario);

ControllerPrimario.$inject = ['principalService'];

function ControllerPrimario(principalService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.informacoes = principalService.informacoes;
}

// Controller Secundário
angular
  .module('minhaApp')
  .controller('ControllerSecundario', ControllerSecundario);

ControllerSecundario.$inject = ['principalService'];

function ControllerSecundario(principalService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.informacoes = principalService.informacoes;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="minhaApp" style="display:inline-flex">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerPrimario as vm" style="border:solid black">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.informacoes.nomeMinimo" />
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="ControllerSecundario as vm" style="border:solid black">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.informacoes.nomeMinimo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Você pode notar no exemplo acima que apenas criei um objeto `informacoes` com um atributo `nomeMinimo` no `service`. Dentro dos `controllers` realizei a atribuição deste atributo para uma variável que pode ser manipulada em dentro de ambos os `controllers` espelhando este comportamento para todos os contextos.